# Writing BigQuery Table from PySpark Dataframe using Dataproc Servereless

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Summary: I'm unable to get a Spark Dataframe and write it to BigQuery Table.

Detail: I'm running a serverless batch job in Dataproc, reading data directly from Bigquery / Cloud Storage, doing some feature engineering and persisting it on BigQuery. However in one routine I'm unable to retrieve the Dataframe and is accusing:

```
22/10/08 08:13:21 WARN BigQueryDataSourceWriterInsertableRelation: It seems that 184 out of 16 partitions have failed, aborting
22/10/08 08:13:21 WARN BigQueryDirectDataSourceWriterContext: BigQuery Data Source writer aedb4dc8-28c5-4118-9dcc-de2ef689e75c aborted
```

Not quite sure but it seems like my Spark configuration is unable to deal with the process.
My config is:

```
--properties spark.executor.instances=10,spark.driver.cores=16,spark.executor.cores=16
```

My writing code:

```
user_item_interaction_df.write.format("bigquery").option("writeMethod", "direct").mode("overwrite").save()
```

BTW I'm running some Joins and Crossjoins which I know is expensive. The final output table should have something like 33M.

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Can you please open an issue in https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector ?

Comment: Sure thing! Here you go [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the `com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Exceeds 'AppendRows throughput' quota, user_id: ... (status: INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS), you can issue a raise quota request through Google Cloud Console. Be sure to include this full error message in the request description.  Entity: projects/...` error (see [GH issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/797) for more details) it seems that your Spark job is hitting BigQuery too hard.

You can try 2 things to fix this:

1. Request more quota as suggested in the exception
2. Limit the scale of the job by decreasing max number of executors with `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=100` property, for example. Note that default value for this property is `1000`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try for the executor change and lastly for quota increase. Let me get back with the result later.